# Obtaining latitude and longitude from shell using freegeoip

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, ip-geolocation, freegeoip

I'm trying to obtain latitude and longitude using freegeoip from shell. When I try the following commands:

```
$ curl -s --get http://freegeoip.net/json/74.201.113.118 | grep -Po '(?<="latitude":)[^,}]*'

$ curl -s --get http://freegeoip.net/json/74.201.113.118 | grep -Po '(?<="longitude":)[^,}]*'
```

I'm able to obtain some values, but whenever I replace the ip adress with my own, the command just outputs 0. Any idea why?

Comment: May be, your location is not in their database? Where is the location? For Germany it works fine.

Comment: Costa Rica, I'm guessing that it isn't in their database. :/

Comment: Do you use public ip or private ip? I tried one Costa Rica ip and there is data. http://freegeoip.net/json/201.199.180.130

Comment: I was using private ip, just tried with public and it works, thanks for everyone's help! :)

Comment: If you are doing it a lot, you might save the result of the `curl` in a variable  and parse that rather than incurring network latency twice, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was using private ip. Since private ip is location independent, freegeoip.net retrieves nothing. Using public ip instead of private ip solves the problem.